# knp_snappy page break in generated PDF

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I'm working on Symfony2 project to generate PDF from HTML view. Following is from config.yml

```
knp_snappy:
pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     /path/to/my/wkhtmltopdf
    options:
        no-stop-slow-scripts: ~
        enable-javascript: ~
        use-xserver: ~
        page-size: A4
        dpi: 300
```

Now I want to know if the DIV is overlapping on the page edges, if so add a page break before DIV. It is currently displaying as follow.

[image]

I've tried to get the height of DIVs and compare it with height of page, but it didn't work.

Is there any solution to know when DIV is overlapping or auto breaking the page when something is overlapping ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to add style "page-break-inside" to your div:

```
<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">
    ... content ...
</div>
```

`wkhtmltopdf` uses webkit engine. This fact allows you to use styles to control the looks of your PDF.

Comment: I've already tried this, page-break-inside. But it seems not working, may be it unable to determine when particular DIV is overlapping.

Comment: This solved my problem. I was giving 'auto' for page-break-inside, 'avoid' works like a charm!

Comment: I had been fighting with this for hours!!! this completely made my day. thank you

Comment: FYI I think this will not work if parent has `display: flex` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534231/page-break-insideavoid-not-working

Answer (score 7):

I use Bootstrap for layout styling.
To do page breaks works only (for me):

```
<p style="page-break-after: always;"/>
<br/>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "has no effect"?

Comment: @EmilVikström sorry, I updated my answer. I copied my answer wrong from my code.